# Generating a series ID using contents of several vectors of different length

Tags: r

I am trying to generate series IDs and I have been able to do so for the task at hand, but I am trying to make the code more flexible for future use.

Below, you can see how I was generating the ID. They follow a pattern that I am using to build up the ID from its component parts. Currently, this works when I am looking at multiple statistics (`data_type_code`) for one industry across all states. I am trying to think about how I would go about creating `series_id` if I wanted to, say, look at multiple industries, or wanted both seasonally adjusted and not seasonally adjusted figures.
`

```
library(tidycensus)
data(fips_codes)
prefix <- c("SM")
seasonal_adjustment_code <- c("U")
state_code <- unique(fips_codes$state_code)[1:51] 
area_code <- c("00000")
supersector_code <- c("20")
industry_code <- c("000000")
data_type_code <- c("01","02","03") 
var_name_list <- c('employees_thousands', 'avg_weekly_hours', 'avg_hourly_earn')
series_id <- unlist(lapply(1:length(data_type_code), function(x) 
                  paste0(prefix, seasonal_adjustment_code, state_code, 
                         area_code, supersector_code, industry_code, 
                         data_type_code[x])))
```

`

I tried testing out what would happen if I added another industry, but I don't get an ID for every possible combination. I was trying to make `mapply` work but got stumped and now the only idea I have is an atrocious series of nested for loops that loops over the length of each ID component. Would appreciate other ideas that build on this or scrap it entirely!

Thanks!

Comment: Please include a sample of your data or similar data, and your expected output. The code you have provided does not run without the dataset 'fips_codes'

Comment: Apologies, 'fips_codes' is a built-in dataset from tidycensus.

Comment: I have updated my answer using your full data now, I think the function you are looking for is "expand.grid"

expand.grid is a base R function, expand_grid is the tidyverse equivalent, using tidyverse that saves some extra typing of all the column names

Answer (score 0):

I think I've been able to figure out what you wanted without the state_code vector. It looks like you're trying to list all possible combinations of the vectors. Paste0 is vectorised, so the following works:

```r
prefix <- c("SM")
data_type_code <- c("01","02","03") 
paste0(prefix, data_type_code)
#> [1] "SM01" "SM02" "SM03"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

However, if we have more than one vector with length > 1, then the values get 'recycled' so it doesn't actually loop through every combination:

```r
prefix <- c("SM", "X")
data_type_code <- c("01","02","03") 
paste0(prefix, data_type_code)
#> [1] "SM01" "X02"  "SM03"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

It matches the 1st value of prefix with 1st value of data_type_code, 2nd with 2nd, and so on, recycling the first vector (looping back to first value).

To get all possible combinations, we could use expand.grid:

```r
prefix <- c("SM", "X")
data_type_code <- c("01","02","03") 
x <- expand.grid(prefix, data_type_code)
paste0(x$Var1, x$Var2)
#> [1] "SM01" "X01"  "SM02" "X02"  "SM03" "X03"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

UPDATE:

We can expand this out to many columns using tidyverse functions as follows:

```r
library(tidycensus)
#> Warning: package 'tidycensus' was built under R version 4.1.3
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'tidyverse' was built under R version 4.1.3
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.1.3
#> Warning: package 'tibble' was built under R version 4.1.3
#> Warning: package 'tidyr' was built under R version 4.1.3
#> Warning: package 'readr' was built under R version 4.1.3
#> Warning: package 'purrr' was built under R version 4.1.3
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 4.1.3
#> Warning: package 'stringr' was built under R version 4.1.3
#> Warning: package 'forcats' was built under R version 4.1.3

data(fips_codes)
prefix <- c("SM")
seasonal_adjustment_code <- c("U")
state_code <- unique(fips_codes$state_code)[1:51] 
area_code <- c("00000")
supersector_code <- c("20")
industry_code <- c("000000")
data_type_code <- c("01","02","03") 
var_name_list <- c('employees_thousands', 'avg_weekly_hours', 'avg_hourly_earn')

tidyr::expand_grid(
    prefix, seasonal_adjustment_code, 
    state_code, area_code, supersector_code,
    industry_code, data_type_code) %>% 
    tidyr::unite(
        col = "new_code", 
        everything(),
        sep = "",
    )
#> # A tibble: 153 x 1
#>    new_code            
#>    <chr>               
#>  1 SMU01000002000000001
#>  2 SMU01000002000000002
#>  3 SMU01000002000000003
#>  4 SMU02000002000000001
#>  5 SMU02000002000000002
#>  6 SMU02000002000000003
#>  7 SMU04000002000000001
#>  8 SMU04000002000000002
#>  9 SMU04000002000000003
#> 10 SMU05000002000000001
#> # ... with 143 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>